# Convert text file to matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a input text file which can be downloaded here: [DOWNLOAD](http://thebrain.bwh.harvard.edu/uniprobe/downfile.php?gene=Egr1&folder=SCI09&type=primary&RC=0)

I want to convert the text file to a count.matrix which looks like this:

```
    1 2 3 4 5 6
  A 3 0 0 0 0 0
  C 0 3 0 0 0 0
  T 0 0 3 0 0 0
  G 0 0 0 3 3 3
```

This gives the following sequence of interest: ACTGGG

The text file holds probability scores (count/N)
I need to filter out all the values with has an A and that will be the first row of the matrix, the second row will be the C followed by all the values which C holds, and so on!
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: How does the first data frame relate to those matrices? It contains completely different values and names?

Comment: and how does the 2nd relate to 3rd mlist (`dput`).

Comment: Thats the problem! i already have a set of matrices but want to create other matrices. This matrices are used for scoring and i want to use the set where i only have a data frame from

Comment: @Arun i took other matrices from the same big list. Just some random examples!

Comment: You want us to find out the transformation between the columns of your data frame and the three matrices? I would say it's nearly impossible, given that you provide no information about what this all is about. As there are letters A, C, G and T, I would guess this has something to do with genetics?

Comment: *How* does one get from the data.frame to your matrix? If you've no clue, how can we?

Comment: Columns from that dataframe can't be made like the others, which are four rows... How about giving an example of what you actually want your output to look like?

Comment: @Arun It doesnt matter how big the size of the matrix is. I just want 1 column to be converted to a matrix which looks like the example matrix

Comment: Just to be clear, the example matrices you included are utterly irrelevant... just examples of what a matrix is? All you need to do is post your data, then what you want your data to look like. Your actual data! You've posted a 6 row data.frame - are you expecting 6x1, 3x2, 2x3 or 6x1? Your examples are all four rows!! Can you see why people cannot help?

Comment: Is this question really *that bad* that it's really worth 6 downvotes?! The OP has at least made a fist of including some example data, even if it's all wrong.

Comment: @alexwhan I see why people cannot help. I shouldn’t put the example matrices there. And Just ask how to convert a column to a matrix. I thought it would be nice to show how the matrices i used before looked like. But anyway thanks for the interest!

Comment: There are lots of people keen to help - just meet them halfway! Edit your question to show how you want your matrix to look and you will definitely get a useful answer

Comment: @SanderVanderZeeuw You can turn column of data frame into the matrix just like this: `as.matrix(df$Elf2)`, where `df` is your data frame. But I feel that this isn't what you are really wanting to do

Comment: @SimonO101, I agree. And he's trying to explain at least.

Comment: I stil can't see how your data set is related to the matrix you want to generate. Could you explain why the matrix has 6 columns? How have the 0s and 3s been calculated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to guess what is asked.

Assuming that your data frame is named `df`, you can convert each column to matrix and put it in list using `lapply()`. For example, I converted to matrix with two columns.

`seq_len(ncol(df)` will make sequence of numbers from 1 to number of columns, so conversion will iterate though all columns. Then `matrix()` convert each column to matrix.

```
lapply(seq_len(ncol(df)),function(i) matrix(df[,i],ncol=2))
[[1]]
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.1682512 0.1589936
[2,] 0.1583613 0.1583613
[3,] 0.2294395 0.1401881

[[2]]
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.1654002 0.1563962
[2,] 0.1423133 0.1283551
[3,] 0.1913303 0.1068051

[[3]]
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.2558522 0.3320734
[2,] 0.2304359 0.1847167
[3,] 0.2934963 0.1893830
```